# How to think about dual space of a certain space of Lipschitz functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mg.metric-geometry, measure-theory

Consider the following Banach space (for concreteness):

$$X=Lip(\bar{\mathbb{B}}^n)=\{f\in C^0(\bar{\mathbb{B}}^n): \Vert f \Vert_L<\infty \}$$
where
$$
\bar{\mathbb{B}}^n=\{\mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{R}^n: |\mathbf{x}|\leq 1\}
$$
is the closed ball and
$$
\Vert f \Vert_L=\sup_{\bar{\mathbb{B}}^n}|f| +\sup_{\mathbf{x}\neq \mathbf{y}\in \bar{\mathbb{B}}^n} \frac{|f(\mathbf{x})-f(\mathbf{y})|}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}|}
$$ 
is one of the usual versions of a lipschitz norm.

I'm curious what is the best way to think about the (topological) dual space $X^*$ of $X$ as this space is a bit mysterious to me.

For instance, it's clear that any finite (signed) measure on $\bar{\mathbb{B}}^n$ can be thought of as an element of $X^*$, but one should also have elements that look like differences of infinite measures whose supports are sufficiently close and whose ``relative mass" is finite.  Are there other natural elements?

Any references (in particular those that are more concrete and less abstract) would be appreciated.

**Edit:**
I guess (please correct me if I am wrong) a fairly pathological element in the dual would be
something like
$$
\mu=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \left( 2^i \delta_{2^{-2i}}-2^{i} \delta_{-2^{-2i}}\right)
$$
on $\mathbb{B}=[-1,1]$.

Are there any natural subsets on which one can restrict and have a less crazy situation?  For instance, fix a Radon measures $\mu$ on $\mathbb{B}^n$ (the open ball) with $\mu(\mathbb{B}^n)=\infty$.  Is the subspace

$$Z=\{T\in X^*: T=\nu-\mu: \nu \mbox{ a Radon measure}\}$$
any nicer?

Comment: The space you describe contains an isomorphic copy of $l^\infty$. Its dual is wild.

Comment: @NikWeaver Any interesting ways to tame it?  For instance, I'm actually interested in something like the following: I have a fixed Radon measure $\mu$ (of infinite mass) on $\mathbb{B}^n$ (the open ball) and am interested in the set of measures $\nu$ on $\mathbb{B}^n$ so that $\nu-\mu$ lives in $X^*$.

Comment: I think you want to look at the predual, which is variously known as the "Arens-Eels" or "Lipschitz-free" space. For specific information about the measures which live there see *Functional Analysis* by Kantorovich and Rubenstein. I don't have the reference handy but it can be found in my book on Lipschitz algebras.

Comment: As a linear space, $Z$ is isomorphic to a subspace of Radon measures, so yes, it is nicer. I suppose you would like to say something nice about the norm on $Z$.

Comment: I think a predual is $\mathbb{R}\times( L^1(B^n,\mathbb{R}^n)/N)$, where $N$ is the closed subspace of  $L^1$ fields on $B^n$ with vanishing divergence.

Answer (score 6):

This would be a really long comment, so I've decided to post it as an answer. Hope it helps!

**Disclaimer.** I'm still learning FA, and my answer is based on my blurred understanding of the subject. I hope experts here will (in)validate this.

On a metric space $X=(X,d)$, let $\mathcal M(X)$ be the set of all measures and $\mathcal M_0(X)$ be the subset of measures $\mu$ for which $\mu(X)=0$. Define $\|\cdot\|_{KR}:\mathcal M(X) \rightarrow \mathbb R$ by

$$
\|\mu\|_{KR} := \inf_{\nu \in \mathcal M_0(X)}\|\nu\|_0 + \|\mu-\nu\|_{TV},
$$

where

- $\|\mu-\nu\|_{TV}$ is the total-variation between $\mu$ and $\nu$
- $\|\nu\|_0 := \underset{\gamma \in \Phi_\nu}{\inf}\int_{X \times X}d(x,x')d\gamma(x,x')$ and $\Phi_\nu$ is the subset of nonnegative measures $\gamma$ on $X \times X$ such that $\gamma(X \times B) - \gamma(B \times X) = \nu(B)$ every Borell subset $B$ of $X$.

Let $\|f\|_L := \max(\|f\|_\infty, L(f))$ be the *bounded-Lipschitz* norm on $Lip(X)$. Then

> **Theorem.** *$(\mathcal M(X),\|\cdot\|_{KR})$ is a normed vector space and the dual pairing*
> $$
> \langle f, \mu\rangle := \int_{X} fd\mu,\;for\;(f,\mu) \in Lip(X) \times \mathcal M(X)
> $$
> *establishes an isometric isomorphism between $(Lip(X), \|.\|_L)$ and the topological dual of $(\mathcal M(X),\|\cdot\|_{KR})$.*

This result goes back to Kantorovich and Rubenstein (hence "KR"), and is well-documented in  [Hanin '92](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a743/259faccd385995057e143a8577c73a23e998.pdf?_ga=2.60118829.1898643625.1573059477-623881584.1573059477) (see Theorem 0 there).

Comment: Yep, by "measures" I mean "signed measures".

Comment: In Hanin it is assumed that X is compact. However, the "main" Kantorovich-Rubenstein theorem (that the Wasserstein 1-distance is in duality with Lipschitz functions with the Lipschitz norm) has been extended to separable metric spaces. Does what you're saying extend as well, or is it necessary to assume that X is compact?

Answer (score 3):

The space of Lipschitz functions is the space $B^1_{\infty,\infty}$, so its dual is basically the space of distributions $B^{-1}_{1,1}$. A natural example of an element in the dual that isn't represented by a Radon measure is white noise in dimension $1$. As a probabilist, I certainly wouldn't call that "crazy" so I am not sure how to interpret your question about the "less crazy situation" ;-)